# background-image not working with encodeURIComponent

Tags: javascript, css, background-image, encodeuricomponent

I was expecting this to work

```
var url = 'http://path_to_some_image.jpg';
$('body').css('background-image', "url('" + encodeURIComponent(url) + "')");
```

But i get 404 not found errors.
Is there a reason why browsers can't handle encoded urls in css ?

If I use the raw url it works, but what if the url contains quotes and stuff? I'd have to use regex to replace them manually :/

Comment: You shouldn't encode it. Encoding it returns http%3A%2F%2Fpath_to_some_image.jpg

Answer (score 2):

You should do `encodeURI`

```
var url = 'http://path_to_some_image.jpg';
$('body').css('background-image', "url('" + encodeURI(url) + "')");
```

The difference is

**encodeURI** assumes that the input is a complete URI that might have some characters which need encoding in it.

**encodeURIComponent** will encode everything with special meaning, so you use it for components of URIs such as